# How to translate "foam peanuts", "packing peanuts", "styrofoam popcorn", "packing noodles"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been unable to find a translation for this item. They are fragments of white polystyrene, that are added in a box (when there is enough space left in it) in order to reduce the impacts of transportation, so the item in the center of the box is not damaged.

Answer (score 3):

> styrofoam = polistireno
>   https://books.google.com/books?id=f0Zunqj2fa0C&pg=PA416&lpg=PA416&dq=Styrofoam

- ero = piece
- eroj de polistireno = pieces of styrofoam
- polistireneroj = pieces of styrofoam

Comment: Mi samopinias kun Lumo5. Kompreneble vi povas uzi aliajn esprimojn, depende de la formo de la polistireneroj: polistirenaj buloj, polistirenaj nuksoj, polistirenaj nudeloj, polistirenaj nudeloj ...